# what impact will it does on site performance if .htaccess file is loaded with hundred's of URL redirection..?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have to redirect bulk of pages to new URL's and if I put all them in .htaccess file, will it get overload and decrease site's performance..??

Please let me know if there are any alternatives to dynamically edit .htaccess file.

Thanks

Comment: Each entry makes Apache to work a little, so yes there should be some decrease, that's for granted, now if you want to know it's measure you need to measure and benchmark

Comment: Instead of doing it in .htaccess if i make to redirect in index page itself , how will it affects on performance...

Comment: have the links  special format or something?

Answer (score 1):

First notice that using .htaccess files or even allwing the use of .htaccess file is decreasing performances. As you are telling Apache to make I/O on the filesystem, seeking for .htaccess files on the directory tree. So for a better performance having a `AllowOverride None` on a `<Directory />` (so from the root directory) is better, and of course you should'nt modify the AllowOverride setting in any subdirectory.

Now, if you a .htacess with a lot of rules, or a `<Directory /path/to/my/directory>` with a lot of rules, which is quite the same, except the second version will be read on startup and not for every request, then you will of course slow down youyr apache process as he must check all the rules. But this is usually quite fast. The best thing is to track it via some tools like autobench, httpperf, webinject, ab, etc.

There is a way in mod_rewrite to speed up the rewriting process when you all a lot of rules using the same scheme. It's [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewritemap.html). When using rewriteMap with a hash file you will of course have something with better speed. But rewriteMap requires that you forget about .htaccess dumb files and that you really use apache configuration files to edit your apache configuration (`/etc/apache/*`). So you need an adminisstrative access on this configuration.

And at the end of your question you are talking about editing dynamically your .htaccess. If your rewrites are really dynamic I would forget about using the webserver to handle that, and push the rewriting policy into the application code (PHP/C#/etc). Or you could also use the `prg:` option of rewriteMap and write your own perl, python or anything else daemon script, called by apache's mod-rewrite on each request, providing the rewrite policy. And the rewriting performance will then depend on your programing skills.

Answer (score -1):

I belived, it will not degrade the perfomance in huge , althout the overload on apache server will definately increses....It's also depend on your bandwidth and speed of RAM on your server, if it is good then, I belived you will find any mager issue..

In my local environment, I am using WAMP, which allow me add /remove module dynamically, you can use cpanel also, which allow you add/edit many items dynamically for your apache server
http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/EasyApache3/WebHome

In Addition, you can active and set your virtual host setting uncommeting below lines from your httpds.conf file

LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so

## Virtual hosts

Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf and afterword you can add you all your hundres of virtual host in same file i.e conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf